# Method behinds "interp2" command

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I always use `interp2` to interpolate my data in MATLAB.
But I want to know what kind of algorithm is really used when running that command, such as [Local Weight Regression](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume4/cohn96a-html/node7.html) (LWR) or something.

Comment: What do you mean? You specify the method when calling `interp2`, and if you don't it's simply linear interpolation. Regression has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As I know, there are many methods to perform interpolation, such as LWR, etc. So I want to know the exact name of the method when MATLAB runs interp2 command. I need to write it in a progress report but Mathematics is not my major. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: LWR is not interpolation, it is a form of non-parametric ***regression***. It is a completely different concept. The method of interpolation used is **LINEAR** interpolation unless you *specify* a different method by adding the `'method'` flag in which case it will use the method you specify e.g. asking for `'cubic'` will make it use *cubic spline* interpolation. This is all quite clear in the doc page for `interp2`.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan. My boss told me that LWR is a kind of interpolation method. I just asked him again after reading your comment. He still claimed that LWR is a kind of interpolation method. So someone (you or him) may miss something. btw, I will write "linear interpolation method" into my report. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your boss is wrong. Interpolation will pass through every single data point (i.e. join the dots). Regression minimizes the error between a line of best fit and the data points but does not necessarily pass through any. They are completely different conceptually and mathematically.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan. Your explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `doc interp2`, you'll see that you can specify one of four different methods that `interp2` can use: nearest neighbour interpolation, linear interpolation, cubic spline interpolation, or cubic interpolation.

If you don't specify one of those explicitly, it will use the default method, which is linear interpolation.